# How to use `DSolve` with y'' and y' in the same argument?

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to solve the differential equation $y''(x)=xy'(x)$ in Mathematica. I'm not sure if it *can* be solved analytically.

This is what I have tried:

```
DSolve[y''[x]/y'[x] == x, y[x], x]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica answers with an error:

> `DSolve::deqn` Equation or list of equations expected instead of `True` in the first argument `True`

This looks more like a syntax error than a statement that the equation cannot be solved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Clear[Derivative]` or restarting your kernel.  You probably typed something like ``y''[x] = x y'[x[`` at some point during your session, with a single `=`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if this was a FAQ..

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Bass, No problem.  It's a hard one to find on the site or to track down.  Searching for the message name `DSolve::deqn` will yield a hit.  (And that's the reason I added it to your post.)

Comment: In[70]:= DSolve[y''[x]/y'[x] == x, y[x], x]

Out[70]= {{y[x] -> C[2] + Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] C[1] Erfi[x/Sqrt[2]]}}